# Spring Boot application cannot find security.tld with JspTagLib and Freemarker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, freemarker

I'm writing an application that needs to get the user's security information on the front end. I've seen many posts/articles/pieces of documentation on using spring security tag libs. I've added the dependancy and have :

`<#assign security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" ]`

in my template. I believe the issue is that, according to the JSP specification, tag libraries are supposed to be found under META-INF. I don't think I have one of those. I found that I could override the TagLibFactory that the freemarker servlet uses to find the tags, but I have been unable to do so. Does anyone have any insight into this issue?

I'd appreciate it a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This apparently does not work in the current versions of Spring Boot.  See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/907) for some discussion.  If you want to see how to get some of it yourself see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893767/spring-security-context-for-freemarker) that has some Rob Winch input.

According to Dave Syer they do not really encourage putting JSP in the Freemarker implementation and would prefer to have Spring Security ship a FreeMarker tag library.  Someone asked for this here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3275.  I started my own macros to use and maybe we can see how to get them included in Spring Security.